# How can I stabilize a sign on a dowel in a pot?

Tags: material-selection, wood

I made a pumpkin sign that is secured to a dowel. I want to put it in a pot on my porch. What is the best option to keep it straight and secure?

I thought of using concrete or stones, but I am leaning towards making a clay bottom attaching that to wood, and then adding some sand and rock to help out.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask should not be particularly difficult, but it depends on your material selection. Depth of pot and length of dowel may be the most important aspects. A photo would be helpful.

Consider that stones surrounding the dowel will provide for a secure mount, especially if you vibrate the pot by tapping on it (gently if clay) until the stones settle into place. Using stones alone is likely to be successful and will provide for easy removal.

If you want to go one step beyond, insert a piece of scrap plastic pipe of sufficient diameter to hold the dowel. This may allow the sign to rotate in the wind. If that is not desired, omit the plastic pipe.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I did attach 2 pics. 1 of the bottom of the sign and 1 of the pot. Can you take a peak and give me your thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Photos did not make it, no peeking allowed at this point.

Comment: I've done something very similar to hold a small parasol, though my scrap tube was galvanised steel. It worked very well

Comment: You could use plaster of paris in place of stones if you wanted a more permanent fix. The suggested piece of pipe of proper diameter centered in the plaster would let you change out the sign.